# pandas MultiIndex degeneration

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a multiindex with lexsort-depth 7 for a dataframe. But, on several depths of the index I only have the same value. The Pandas multiindex constructor excludes those with the same value. Is there any way I can keep them?

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

labels = 
 [(0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0)]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(labels)
index.lexsort_depth
>>> 2        # what I want is 7 here
```

Comment: Why would you expect 7 there? Because your index is not sorted in all levels. `index.sortlevel()[0].lexsort_depth` gives 7

Comment: @joris thank you for your answer, actually want I want is to set the number of Index to 7 which sortlevel seems not to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the MI first for it to have full lexsort depth:

```
In [11]: index = index.order()

In [12]: index.lexsort_depth
Out[12]: 7
```

*At the moment it is not sorted past the second level (where 5 is before 4).*